# Any speech recognition library to recognize characters from audio file?

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

The title says it all - I would like to recognize the characters in an audio file (for example "hello" as "heh - lo") as opposed to a library that recognizes the actual word.

Comment: You probably meant to recognize [Phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) or [Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable). A query on Google with the right word should give you a quick answer.

Comment: thank you! I will try to make a new search on google with those particular keywords.

Comment: making the new search looks like this post could be a duplicate of this one! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705028/convert-sound-to-list-of-phonemes-in-python/30705104#30705104