# Phoneme extraction using Pocketsphinx: RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pocketsphinx, phoneme

I am new to stack overflow. I am trying to achieve the results with the code provided in the citation below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705028/convert-sound-to-list-of-phonemes-in-python

However, this code isn't compiling successfully without errors. I am getting the following error. How do I get around this problem? Thanks.

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        17 
>        18 # Decode streaming data.
>   ---> 19 decoder = Decoder(config)
>        20 
>        21 decoder.start_utt()
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py in
>   **init**(self, *args)
>       271         **init**(Decoder self, Config config) -> Decoder
>       272         """
>   --> 273         this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
>       274         try:
>       275             self.this.append(this)
>
> RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pocketsphinx decoder initialization returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941443/pocketsphinx-decoder-initialization-returns-1)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks for taking the time to help. The issue was with the  model I downloaded for training from sourceforge.net . Here's the correct link for the model: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/