# Is there a python library I could use to convert audio to phonemes?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, phonetics

I'm working on a project for which I need to convert audio to phonemes. What I'm looking for is something like this. I would be good if along with the phonemes I could also get the timestamps at which they occur

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert sound to list of phonemes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705028/convert-sound-to-list-of-phonemes-in-python)

Comment: These types of questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, but there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Allosaurus, a universal (~2000 lang) phone recognizer to give you IPA phonemes. On a sample wave file, I did downloaded the latest model and tried this in Python3.

```sh
python3 -m allosaurus.bin.download_model -m latest
python3 -m allosaurus.run -i sample.wav
```

taken from  [convert sound to list of phonemes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705028/convert-sound-to-list-of-phonemes-in-python)